# Store id values as scalar variable to then use in 2nd query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I thought it may be best to ask this in a different way and focus on the specific part I am having an issue with at the moment.

So I have this first query that I will be using:

```
        private const string Items = @"
SELECT 
  id.ItemId, id.ItemDetailID, id.Status, id.Number
, id.Title, id.CreatedDate, id.WithdrawnDate
, RevisionNumber = id.MajorRevisionNumber + ISNULL(id.RevisionNumberOffset, 0)
FROM AgilityItemView v
JOIN ItemDetail id
    ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
WHERE id.[Status] in ('Released', 'Withdrawn')
AND V.VersionRank = 1 AND V.[Type] = 'Document'";
```

From here what I want to do is store the id values as the scalar variable as this will be used in the 2nd query below:

```
        private const string LastModifiedDate = @"
WITH History AS (
    SELECT id.ItemID, id.ItemDetailID, ih.ActionedDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.ItemID ORDER BY ih.ActionedDate DESC) AS vn
    FROM AgilityItemView v
    JOIN ItemDetail id
        ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
    JOIN ItemHistory ih
        ON ih.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID 
    WHERE id.[Status] in ('Released', 'Withdrawn')
    AND V.VersionRank = 1 AND V.[Type] = 'Document'
    AND ih.Action in (
      'Create','Edit','ItemCreatedByChanged'
    , 'ItemCustomPropertiesChanged','ItemNumberChanged','ItemRoleChanged'
    , 'ItemTitleChanged','Release','Restore'
    , 'ReturnToDraft','Revise','Withdraw'
    )
)
SELECT ItemId, LastModifiedDate = ActionedDate
FROM History
WHERE vn = 1
AND ItemId = @ItemID";
```

As you can see the scalar variable is "@ItemID".

What I will be attempting to do is to use both these queries to create a data table. These will then be use to create a csv file with the use of csvhelper. The columns for this file come from the ExtractDocument.cs file.

```
public record ExtractDocument
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; init; }
    public string FileType { get; init; }
    public string Status { get; init; }
    public string Number { get; init; }
    public string Title { get; init; }
    public string Function { get; init; }
    public string Discipline { get; init; }
    public string Country { get; init; }
    public string Asset { get; init; }
    public string Language { get; init; }
    public string URLLink { get; init; }
    public string SubmitFeedback { get; init; }
    public string ViewItemLink { get; init; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; init; }
    public DateTime? ReleasedDate { get; init; }
    public string? WithdrawnDate { get; init; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; init; }
    public int RevisionNumber { get; init; }
    public string Author { get; init; }
    public string Verifier { get; init; }
    public string Reviewer { get; init; }
    public string Approver { get; init; }
    public string SecurityGroup { get; init; } 

}
```

So the first query will get the values for the columns: ItemID, ItemDetailID, Status, Number, Title, CreatedDate and WithDrawnDate.

The second query will get the value for LastModifiedDate. There will be a couple other queries for the rest but for now I am focusing on just getting this working with the first 2.

As you will be able to see there is also an ItemID column in the LastModifiedDate query, what I'm looking to do is to match up the last modified date by the ids. So as an example if there was the id 245 from the 1st query, I would want the value from the second query where the id is also 245 and have that in the same row of the data table if that makes sense?

So how can I go about doing this? I'm assuming I need to find a way to store the ids from the 1st query but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

I had tried this:

```
    private DataTable GetData(string itemsQuery, string modifiedData, string roleHoldersData, string customPropertiesData, ExtractDocument extract)
    {

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        using var cnn = new SqlCommand(itemsQuery, connection);

        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        adapter.SelectCommand = cnn;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Table(0)");
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = modifiedData;
        cnn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", extract.ItemId);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Table(1)");

        ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[1]);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        adapter.Fill(dt);

        return dt;

    }
```

but I feel like I'm off the mark with this as it only just seems to store the 1st query in the data table

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I've been using Microsoft SQL Server, is that what you're meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into it more, it did seem the best way was to join up the queries so it would be one big one rather than 4 smaller ones to do what I was trying to do.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
        private const string ExtractData = @"
WITH ExtractData AS (
SELECT id.ItemID, id.ItemDetailID, id.Status, id.Number,
id.Title, id.CreatedDate, id.WithdrawnDate, id.ReleaseDate, ih.ActionedDate,
RevisionNumber = id.MajorRevisionNumber + ISNULL(id.RevisionNumberOffset, 0), OwnershipRoleTitle = IOR.Title, 
    HolderTitle = P.Title, CustomPropertyTitle = cp.Title, cpi.ItemTitle
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.ItemID ORDER BY ih.ActionedDate DESC) AS vn
FROM AgilityItemView v
JOIN ItemDetail id
ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
JOIN ItemHistory ih
ON ih.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID
 JOIN dbo.ItemDetailOwnershipRole IDOR
 ON Id.ItemDetailID = IDOR.ItemDetailID
 JOIN dbo.ItemOwnershipRole IOR
    ON IDOR.ItemOwnershipRoleID = IOR.ItemOwnershipRoleID
 JOIN  dbo.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleHolder IDOH
    ON IDOH.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleID = IDOR.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleID
 JOIN  dbo.AgilityItemView P
    ON IDOH.ItemOwnershipRoleHolderItemID = P.ItemID and p.VersionRank = 1
JOIN CustomPropertyItemReference cpir
    ON cpir.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID
JOIN CustomPropertyItem cpi
    ON cpi.CustomPropertyItemID = cpir.ReferenceItemID
JOIN CustomProperty cp
    ON cp.CustomPropertyID = cpi.CustomPropertyID
WHERE id.[Status] in ('Released', 'Withdrawn')
AND V.VersionRank = 1 AND V.[Type] = 'Document'
AND ih.Action in (
      'Create','Edit','ItemCreatedByChanged'
    , 'ItemCustomPropertiesChanged','ItemNumberChanged','ItemRoleChanged'
    , 'ItemTitleChanged','Release','Restore'
    , 'ReturnToDraft','Revise','Withdraw'
    )
AND IOR.Title IN ('Reviewer', 'Drafter', 'Owner', 'Approver')
AND cp.Title in (
'Office Location', 'Governence', 'Type'
, 'HSEQ', 'Approver'
)
    )

SELECT ItemID, ItemDetailId, Status, Number, Title, CreatedDate, ReleaseDate,
WithdrawnDate, LastModifiedDate = ActionedDate, RevisionNumber, OwnershipRoleTitle, HolderTitle,
CustomPropertyTitle, ItemTitle
FROM ExtractData
WHERE vn = 1

;";
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure how I can go about combining these queries

You need to refactor the SQL to output the proper *unioned* data which can be converted to CSV. Put it in a stored procedure and pull the data into your program to output it into CSV.

Comment: I can sort of get what you are saying but I'm not sure how to go about this. Do you happen to have a link of a good example for something like this?

Comment: You will have to individually research what to do on each of the coding paradigms you seek and create your code. There is no one magic example which you seem to be asking for...research and then if you have individual issues, then ask on each one individually, and not all together. In other words you need to focus this question and research each area. GL

Comment: I wasn't looking for a perfect example of what I'm trying to do, just merely something that would help explain your answer